# Etymology of lamotialnini, a type of cicada

Tags: etymology, science, biology, taxonomy

[Lamotialnini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamotialnini) are a tribe of cicadas. I haven't been able to find an etymology for this very odd-looking term and am wondering where it derives from. I'd appreciate any comments.

Comment: You might have to ask this question over at [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=etymology) or at Latin.SE (if it is inspired by Latin)

Comment: -ini is the usual suffix for a [tribe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tribe_(biology)), just as -dae is for family. I'd guess the Lamotial bit comes from Madagascar or Indonesia or wherever the creepy-crawlies live.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It is looking for a derivation of the Latin.

Comment: The earliest occurrences of [***Lamotialnini***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Lamotialnini%22&sca_esv=597188272&tbas=0&biw=1536&bih=747&sxsrf=ACQVn0_Dg2q3ohTJchgLsBzKYW3utBvfmg%3A1704885885883&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1800%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1970&tbm=bks) and "precursor" ***Lamotialna*** in Google Books are all in ***French***, so that's probably where you should look for an "origin".

Comment: Almost certainly eponymous. Place, person ...?

Comment: Seems to have been named by French entomologist [Michel Boulard](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Boulard)